# Matplotlib 3D graph giving different plot when used inside a function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have written two functions. The first function takes in a distance matrix of point vectors and does Mult-Dimensional Scaling of the point to 3D and returns a matrix (pos)with points transformed to 3 dimensional space such that the spacing is reduced in the same proportion. In the first function you will also see I have pickled my 'pos' matrix to disk.

The second function is a plotting function which takes that pos matrix as input and plots the points .

```
def MDS(dist):
    """ This function is going to get the Multi-dimensional scaling"""

    # Visualising distance using MDS

    from sklearn.manifold import MDS
    # two components as we're plotting points in a two-dimensional plane
    # "precomputed" because we provide a distance matrix
    # we will also specify `random_state` so the plot is reproducible.
    mds = MDS(n_components=3, dissimilarity="precomputed", random_state=1)

    pos = mds.fit_transform(dist) 

    # Pickling the MDS estimator
    outfile=open("MDS_"+z[c]+".p",'wb')
    cPickle.dump(mds,outfile)
    outfile.close()

    outfile=open("MDS_pos"+z[c]+".p",'wb')
    cPickle.dump(pos,outfile)
    outfile.close()

    return pos


# Visualising the plot

def plotMds(pos,outcome):
    """Plotting the MDS output"""

    header=list(outcome)
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Terminated')
    green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Completed Positive')
    blue_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Completed Negative')
    plt.legend(handles=[red_patch,green_patch,blue_patch])
    plt.title('MDS by'+z[c])
    for x, y, w, name in zip(pos[:, 0], pos[:,1], pos[:, 2], header):
        if(name=='Completed Negative'):
            color='blue'
        elif(name=='Completed Positive'):
            color='green'
        else:
            color='red'
    ax.scatter(x, y, w,s=55,c=color)

    fig.savefig('mds_'+z[c]+'.png')
```

I get the following output as the saved .png file.

[image]
This image is giving weird output as I have 5000 points to plot. And all it gives is just one point.

But if I take the same plotting code written above and unpickle the pos matrix which I pickled in the first function and plot it separately outside a function definition, I get a correct plot.

```
infile=open("MDS_posI.p",'rb')
check=pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()


infile=open("outcomeI.p",'rb')
outcome=pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()

header=list(outcome)
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Terminated')
green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Completed Positive')
blue_patch=mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Completed Negative')
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch,green_patch,blue_patch])
for x, y, z, name in zip(check[:, 0], check[:, 1], check[:, 2], header):
    if(name=='Completed Negative'):
        color='blue'
    elif(name=='Completed Positive'):
        color='green'
    else:
        color='red'
    ax.scatter(x, y, z,s=65,c=color)
```

If you see all I am doing here is taking the same plotting code from above and unpickling the pos matrix which I created in the first function and plotting it. Just that this time the plotting code is not inside a function definition. Here is the output.

[image]

This plot does makes sense as I do have 5000 points to plot.

Can someone help me understand what is going wrong here that the first code is just saving the plot with one point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `ax.scatter(...)` inside the `for` loop, otherwise it will only plot the last point of the loop.